# Why JVM does not recover after network drive flicks?

Tags: java, jar, jvm, citrix

Java application is running from a Jar on a network drive. If Jar file becomes unavailable for some reason then there is NoClassDefFoundError as expected. Like in example network connection is lost. But what I find odd is that the application will still crash completely and will not recover if Failover occurs on the network drive where Jar file is located.

Failover means Network Drive doesn't change and it only flicks briefly and becomes available again right away but it changes some sort of internal low level drive (the infrastructure guys call it Node). After the Failover happens (node is changed) all users that were connected to application which is running in a Citrix server get the same exception.

I would have thought, that once network drive is back online the JVM should be able to recover, but it seems it is trying to obtain classes from the old node where Jar was located and not from the new Node. Does anyone know why JVM will present this behavior ?

Comment: It only makes one attempt to load the JAR file. It copies it to a local temp file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, if Jar file is loaded to a local temp file, then it doesn't make sense that Java application gives an error when Network drive becomes unavailable. The scenario I have described occurs when Java application is running, meaning, it has successfully loaded in memory everything it needs to run from the Jar until the point failover occurs, and failover takes about a second or less, and after it has happened the Jar remains available in the same network drive but the internal "node" has changed.

Comment: But the JAR file *can't* be loaded to a temp file, *because of the network error.*

Comment: The network error occurs after jar classes have been loaded in memory and application is running, please if don't understand the question then no need to respond. Someone has already answered with useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM only opens a file once and keeps the handle open to read classes from it when needed. When the network drive gets disconnected the handle becomes invalid.

One presumably could write a classloader that tries to reopen the file and verifies that it is indeed the same file as before, e.g. via hashing, but the standard implementation does not since filesystems are assumed to be reliable.

Most other executable programs started from network drives are likely to experience similar problems.

You should use a clustering network filesystem that does not invalidate application-visible handles and instead does failover transparently.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation very useful!